# Визуальный "редактор" HTML с возможностью программного управления

Tags: c#, html5, bootstrap, vb.net, vba

Имеется задача.

Открываем страницу верстки или просто сайта.
Выделяем визуально какой то блок DOM модели.
И далее любым возможным образом отправляем выделенный кусок HTML кода например по XML-RPC или каким то другим методом на определенный сервер.

Например такое можно сделать в FrontPage 2000-2003 применив VBA. В нем можно визуально выделить нужный блок кода на странице и что нибудь с ним сделать программно. Пройтись по нему, спарсить и т.д. Но проблема в том что FrontPage 2003 не сможет отобразить блочную верстку, а отобразит кашу из блоков.

Идеальный вариант, сделать надстройку для хрома и визуально дергать блоки, но как добавить меню для DevTools к сожалению не нашел.

Может кто посоветует редактор именно визуальный, чтобы в нем подсвечивались блоки при наведении мышкой, с возможностью добавить контекстное меню и далее запостить данные куда нужно, на каком нибудь языке программирования (наверное кроме C++, а что-нибудь типа C#, VB.NET, Java). Подобное реализовано в Datacol7, там при конструировании проекта парсера можно визуально блокам произвольного сайта задавать куда они будут парситься и как.